# Fading animation with class looping between list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have some code that I ran across that is exactly what I'm looking for to loop between list items in a efficient fashion. My problem is that I need them the 'active' li to fadeOut() before the 'next' li can fadeIn().

What I have now transitions blatantly and I'm looking for something a little more 'sexy', which is why I would like it to fade between transitions.

I have tried strategically placing set time out functions but that ends up with the containing div changing in size through transitions (obviously because I'm switching with incorrect timing).

Here is my code that I have for transitioning:

```
$(function () {

    $(".header-featured-blocks").css("padding-top", "0px");

    var $lis = $('.header-featured-blocks li');
    $cur = $lis.first().addClass('active');
    $next = $cur.next().addClass('next');

    setInterval(function () {
        $cur.removeClass('active');
        $cur = $next.removeClass('next').addClass('active');

        $next = $cur.next();
        if (!$next.length) {
            $next = $lis.first();
        }
        $next.addClass('next');
    }, 5000);
});
```

And here is my failed attempt at trying to get smooth transitions. Hopefully this will help out with others trying to understand what I'm trying to achieve.

My thought process was: Fade out the current 'active', wait until it is faded out and then remove the 'active' class from the element. While that is happening, set a time out for 500 milliseconds while the previous mentioned action is happing so the 'next' element doesn't become 'active' until the previous 'active' has been removed from the 'active' class.

Like I have previously stated, my timing is off. And I know this because if I were doing this correctly, the transitioning li elements wouldn't be bouncing all over in their containing div.

```
$(function () {

    var $lis = $('.header-featured-blocks li'),
    $cur = $lis.first().addClass('active'),
    $next = $cur.next().addClass('next');

    setInterval(function () {

       $cur.fadeOut(500).delay(500).removeClass('active');
       setTimeout(function(){ 
           $cur = $next.removeClass('next').fadeIn(500).addClass('active'); 
       }, 500);

        $next = $cur.next();
        if (!$next.length) {
            $next = $lis.first();
        }
        $next.addClass('next');
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Could you please try creating a demo for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So based on what I understand, I have made some changes to your jQuery snippet. I have removed the delay and have the list items cross-fade. So while the visible item fades out, the next one fades in. In order for this to work, I need to do some styling changes. I had to make the list items position absolute, so that the cross-fade is all in the same place. I also made all list items hidden and then fade in the first item.

Here is my suggestion:

**CSS:**

```
.header-featured-blocks ul{
    position: relative;
}
.header-featured-blocks li {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function () {
    var $lis = $('.header-featured-blocks li'),
    $cur = $lis.first().addClass('active'),
    $next = $cur.next().addClass('next');
    $cur.fadeIn(500);
    setInterval(function () {
       $cur.fadeOut(500).removeClass('active');
       $cur = $next.removeClass('next').fadeIn(500).addClass('active'); 
        $next = $cur.next();
        if (!$next.length) {
            $next = $lis.first();
        }
        $next.addClass('next');
    }, 5000);
});
```

My sample HTML:

```
    <div id="container" class="header-featured-blocks">
        <ul>
            <li>text 1</li>
            <li>text 2</li>
            <li>text 3</li>
            <li>text 4</li>
            <li>text 5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I think this is a little "sexier" than waiting for one animation to stop in order to start the next. The cross-fade is quite nice.

And just to make it even sexier, we can add a little slide to it:

```
$(function () {
    var $lis = $('.header-featured-blocks li'),
    $cur = $lis.first().addClass('active'),
    $next = $cur.next().addClass('next');
    $cur.fadeIn(500);
    setInterval(function () {
       $cur.fadeOut({duration: 500,queue: false}).animate({marginLeft:10}).removeClass('active');
       $cur = $next.removeClass('next').css({marginLeft:-10}).fadeIn({duration: 500,queue: false}).animate({marginLeft:0}).addClass('active'); 
        $next = $cur.next();
        if (!$next.length) {
            $next = $lis.first();
        }
        $next.addClass('next');
    }, 5000);
});
```

Left me know if you need a demo?

**EDIT:**

Ok, I made a demo anyway:
https://jsfiddle.net/qx3ftL80/

Comment: If this is helpful, please upvote or mark as the correct answer. It would contribute to my stackoverflow reputation. Good luck!

Comment: You truly went above and beyond on this. I really appreciate it. If only people were so helpful on SuperUser with server admin problems! ;-) Thanks!